# In excel, I'm trying to reference a merged cell from another worksheet but it says #value error

Tags: excel

I'm trying to reference another sheet in excel, particularly merged cells. Everytime I do = (cell from another sheet) it says #value.

I've turned format to General already, this hasn't worked.

Comment: Try typing simply `=`, then while the cursor is still there, go to the other sheet and click on the cell you want to reference. It should autofill the correct syntax for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Type into the cell you want to link to the merged cell `=`
2. Click the merged cell and see how it links, usually it links the upper-leftmost cell of the merged range.

You can also try naming the merged cell and referencing it that way.

To name a cell:

1. While the cell is selected, type the name in the box left of the formula bar
2. Hit enter

Answer (score -1):

Mark's answer is probably what you need. I just wanted to include some general tips that are useful and will stop this from happening again.

I have a rule, never merge and center.

Always use `Ctrl+1` which opens up Cell Format. Once Cell Format is open `Right Key + Tab + Down Key` and then choose "Center Across Selection". This will make it look the same as if you used merge & center but it will get rid of all the problems that come with it.